# Does anyone know the options for Devises `authenticate_user!`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

Like the title says, I'm looking for the options for devises automatic class `authenticate_user!`, specifically, I want it to redirect_to to '/' and not '/users/sign_in'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do the following:

In config/initializers/devise.rb:

```
  config.warden do |manager| 
    manager.failure_app = CustomAuthenticationFailure 
  end
```

Create a new file called lib/custom_authentication_failure.rb:

```
  class CustomAuthenticationFailure < Devise::FailureApp 
  protected 
    def redirect_url 
      root_path  #or whatever route in your app that points to '/' 
    end 
  end
```

And this to your config/application.rb:

```
  config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can find your answer here: [Devise Wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki)

In particular, I think this should do the trick:

[Change default sign in and sign out routes](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes)